# Excel 2010 Password Protected Book Accepts More Than One Password

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, microsoft-excel-2010

I use Excel 2010 64 bit (14.0.6023.1000)

A workbook that is being protected by password "flu" and be unprotected by password "flu" OR " ab". Why is that? First of all, I thought beginning with Excel 2007 they started using better password hashing than the old .xls files. Second, "flu" and " ab" have different SHA1 hash.

1) I go to `Review -> Changes -> Protect Workbook`

Structure: Yes

Windows: No

Password: "flu" (no quotations)

2) Confirm password

3) `Review -> Changes -> Protect Workbook`

Password: " ab" (no quotations)

4) Workbook is unprotected

P.S. In case you can't reproduce the issue here is a test file. You can see that both passwords work:
http://www.filefactory.com/file/122vxoqnga4j/test_password_glitch.xlsx

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Maybe you are on a different version of Excel? I recreated the file form scratch and tested it on a different computer. I'm definitely seeing this problem and I can easily reproduce it.

Comment: @Raystafarian I uploaded a file, I can unlock it using both passwords. Note there is a space before ab.

Comment: Can reproduce with that file, excel 2011. I might give a search around security.SE and SO to see if this has been reported, with explanation. Otherwise, with no mentions of it anywhere, the only option would be to report it to MS. [this may be related](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/excel-2007-encryption-strength)